# Change measurement unit in Draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

Can I change the measurement unit of a **Draw.io** diagram?
By default, all the measurements are in `pt` except the page size (in `mm`).

I'd like to enter the shape dimensions in `mm` or `inch` instead of `pt`.

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since October 2019, draw.io is able to work with **millimeters**.
Just select *View > Units > Millimeters* from the draw.io menu.

Comment: Yes it works now. After switching to mm I had to change the grid size to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.. That won't be possible. Convert **mm/inch** to **pt** and work with it. It's tedious, but also the only way
1mm=2.83465pt &
1inch=72pt

Comment: A nice workaround? It is not nice. And I would not call it a workaround. As it is the obvious way to work if this feature is not available.

Comment: As of posting this comment, 1 inch in draw.io is equal to 100 points. Convention dictates that (1 in == 72 pt), but the application doesn't seem to be designed that way.

Comment: By just trying things, I was able to get what appear to be inch-sized major (quarter-inch sized minor) ticks by setting grid to 25 pts. (This bears no obvious relation to 72 pt / in. - but I'm curious if there is one.)

Comment: As of this writing I find that 120 pts is 1 inch. I set the grid to 15 pts to get a 1/8th inch grid (which bears no relation ship to the Ruler markings, which seem to have a tick every 10 points).

I did a 90 point circle bisected by a line and found the diameter, when printed to be 3/4 inch -- exctly as I intended. My print job was at 100% scaling. Page size set to US letter in drawio and for printer.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the comment/answer by @kccricket still works.

> ```
> 1 inch in draw.io is equal to 100 points
> ```

You can simply divide by 100 any `pt` values to get `inch`.

Comment: Experiment. I found that 120 pts seem to map to 1 inch.  There is zero documentation about this. I've no idea why some folks are finding 1 inch = 72 pts, 1 inch = 100 pts, and (myself) 1 inch = 120 pts.

Comment: This is most likely a coincidence caused by your screen resolution.

Comment: Well, I was using a 1920x1080p monitor, it is a bit confusing now!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately imperial measurements don't conform to 100ths of an inch.  You can't effectively use this program to diagram things like architectural details that require dimensioning at 1/16th inch resolution for example because the grid only accepts whole integers.  The best you can do is 1/4" (25/100ths) which is useless.